# WPF - Attach Folder that has many files with clickonce deployment to be installed in user C drive

Tags: wpf, clickonce

I am developing a WPF application, that has a function to run the "CMD" in user pc and navigate to one folder "platform-tools" that included in the application files and execute a command.

```
string Request = " /c" + "cd../../&cd platform-tools& adb reboot ";
 Process procc = new Process();
 ProcessStartInfo procStartInfo2 = new ProcessStartInfo(@"cmd.exe", Request);
```

As we know, when the user install the application in his PC, the application will be located in     C:\Users\""UserName\AppData\Local\Apps\2.0\"random name like: JBJHV6HG7HG"
so its difficult to know where is exactly the "platform-tools" will be installed.

My question is: is there any way i can know how to reach the platform-tools folder by my "Request" in order to rung the adb command?

or

is there a way to install the "platform-tools" in different location like "User's desktop" then i can change the "CD" command in CMD to navigate to user's desktop or C drive?

Comment: Is platform-tools installed together with your application? What are you using to install, clickonce?

Comment: Hi Pavel,
yes it will be installed with my application but in unknown sub folder because i am using clickonce deployment.

Comment: you can try to find this subfolder and invoke command on it, without running `cd` Is `adb` an executable to run and `reboot` is argument for that?

Answer (score 1):

Using the ClickOnce, you won't be able to change the destination install folder due some security features and so on...
you can find out more [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/deployment/clickonce-security-and-deployment?view=vs-2019)

You can get the path of your executing process, and concatenate the folder name to reach the "platform-tools" folder:

```
       //There's two ways to get the current file address from your application (in the end both ends in the same):

          //There's two ways to get the current file address from your application (in the end both ends in the same):

        //getting the filename by the process
        var cc = Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule.FileName;
        //getting the filename by the executing assembly
        var dd = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location;

        //getting the path for that file name
        string assemblyPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(cc);


        var platformTools = string.Concat(assemblyPath, @"/platform-tools/someprocess.exe");
        Process.Start(platformTools);
```